# Same outer structure only one difference between functions

Tags: c++, c++11

I have many functions that do roughly the same apart from the what variable the modify

```
struct example
{
    std::string name;
    std::string category;
};

using ObjName = std::string;
using Value = std::string;

bool updateName(const ObjName &name, const Value& value) ...
bool updateCategory(const ObjName &name,const Value& value)
{
    //  boost optional pointing to struct reference
    auto obj = findOjb(name);
    if (obj)
    {
        obj.get().category = value; // variable name changes 
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

What I am wondering is what I can do to combine the code ? 
I suspect it will involve templates maybe traites/functors but I am unsure of how to approach it any ideas ?

Comment: What is ObjName?  Is that a hashed string or something?  Is Category implicitly convertible to std::string?  Do all of your attributes exist as objects that are convertible to strings?  The code is bit too vague to recommend an optimal solution.

Comment: ObjName and Category is an typedef string I have updated to show that

Comment: I assume also that 'obj' is supposed to be 'rule' - otherwise rule isn't defined anywhere.

Comment: thanks I will update now

Comment: Is `cat` supposed to be `value`? And shouldn't `Value` be `ObjName` in the first function, and `Category` in the second? This is why coming up with an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) is important. There's a very good chance your question would've been answered much quicker if you'd done that.

Comment: I fixed the cat issue but the Value in the first one I kept the same so show that there is little difference between the two functions.

Comment: I am thinking of following http://erdani.com/publications/traits.html and using traits to solve this issue but I am open to suggestions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use lambdas:

```
template <typename Accessor>
bool updateVariable(const ObjName& name, const Value& value, Accessor access) {
    auto obj = findObj(name);
    if (obj)
    {
        access(obj.get()) = value;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
bool updateCategory(const ObjName& name, const Value& value) {
    return updateVariable(name, value,
        [](Example& e) -> Value& { return e.category; });
}
```

This is a bit more flexible than the pointer-to-member solution. You can make it even more flexible by having the lambda do the setting instead of returning a reference.

Comment: I was thinking about using a lambda but I was also exploring traits to see what the difference would be what do you think ?

Comment: I believe traits would simply be more boilerplate.

Answer (score 6):

Reworking Daerst's code to remove that awful `offsetof` in favor of pointers-to-members...

```
struct example
{
    std::string name;
    std::string category;
};

bool updateVariable(const ObjName &name, std::string example::*member, std::string const &value)
{
    // your code ...

    // Access
    rule.get().*member = value

    // rest of your code
}

bool updateName(const ObjName &oldname, const ObjName& newName)
{
    return updateVariable(name, &example::name, newName));
}

bool updateCategory(const ObjName &name, Category &cat)
{
    return updateVariable(name, &example::category, cat));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use something traits like:

```
#include <string>
#include <assert.h>

struct example
{
   std::string name;
   int category;
};

struct nameDesc
{
   typedef std::string valuetype;
   static void set(example& obj, const valuetype& val)
   {
      obj.name = val;
   }
};
struct categoryDesc
{
   typedef int valuetype;
   static void set(example& obj, const valuetype& val)
   {
      obj.category = val;
   }
};


example test; // just for testing...
example& findObj(const std::string &name)
{
   // just for testing...
   return test;
}
template <typename V>
bool update(const std::string &objName, const typename V::valuetype& value)
{
   example& obj = findObj(objName);
   V::set(obj, value);
   return true;
}
bool updateName(const std::string &objName, const std::string& value) { return update<nameDesc>(objName, value); }
bool updateCategory(const std::string &objName, int value) { return update<categoryDesc>(objName, value); }

int main()
{
   update<nameDesc>("objname", "asdf");
   update<categoryDesc>("objname", 1234);
   assert(test.name == "asdf");
   assert(test.category == 1234);

   updateName("objname", "qwer");
   updateCategory("objname", 7890);
   assert(test.name == "qwer");
   assert(test.category == 7890);
   return 0;
}
```

And I'd encourage you having a look at boost::spirit / BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT if possible.

Answer (score -1):

A bit hacky, but this could be a solution (untested code) using [`offsetof`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstddef/offsetof/):

```
struct example
{
    std::string name;
    std::string category;
};

bool updateVariable(const size_t offset, std::string value)
{
    // your code ...

    // ASSIGNMENT: get address, apply offset and assign value
    *(&rule.get() + offset) = cat;

    // rest of your code
}

bool updateName(const ObjName &oldname, const ObjName& newName)
{
    return updateVariable(offsetof(struct example, name), newName));
}

bool updateCategory(const ObjName &name, Category &cat)
{
    return updateVariable(offsetof(struct example, category), cat));
}
```

I assume that `ObjName` and `Category` are `typedef`s of `string` or can be implicitly converted.

You still need to add a one-liner function for each member variable, which is pretty hard to elude in C++ if you want to stick to a hard-coded struct. You might want to consider converting the whole struct definition to data, e.g. loaded from a file, opening other possibilities.

Comment: I am thinking something like http://accu.org/index.php/journals/442 but wanted to know if there was a better way of doing it